# How do I fill a 2d matrix with math.random or null in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, random

I want to either fill in with null or with random numbers (0..50) a matrix.
If "random" is true (it could be either boolean true or false, or int 0 or 1 doesn't matter) , then it will fill the matrix with random numbers up to 50, else , it will fill it with null.

```
public class array 
   {
    protected int N;
    protected int M;
    protected int [][] matrix;

    array(int n, int m, boolean random)
    {
        N=n;
        M=m;
        matrix=new int[n][m];

        if (random==true)

        {
                for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
                    for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
                        matrix[i][j]=null;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
                {
                   matrix[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*50);
                }
        }
    }
```

And then, I'd like to display this

```
    public void display() {
    System.out.println("[ Dimensions = " + this.N + " x " + this.M + " ]");
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
            if (matrix[i][j])!=null) 
            {
                System.out.print(" ["+matrix[i][j].displayString()+"]");
            }
            else
                {System.out.print("[null]");
           System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Is it correct? I get an ''illegal start of expression'' to the if , within display(), among others.

Edit: Apart from the extra or missing (,{ , is it properly written? Would you suggest any other way?

Comment: You've got an extra `)` in the line `if (matrix[i][j])!=null)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `illegal start of expression error` is a compile-time error when the compiler finds an inappropriate statement in the code. The Java compiler, `javac` compiles your source code from top to bottom, left to right and when it sees something inappropriate at the start of an expression, it throws "illegal start of expression" error.
It generally occurs due to either `)` or `{`.Better use an `IDE` for this.

Read more: http://www.java67.com/2016/08/how-to-fix-illegal-start-of-expression-error-in-java.html#ixzz51jH58YDo

And as the comment on your post is mentioning there is an extra `)` in line `if (matrix[i][j])!=null)`

for your second problem try

```
Integer[][] matrix = null;
int[][] array = MoreObjects.firstNonNull(matrix, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited in my code. However, now I get an incompatible type, can't convert to <nulltype> cannot be converted to int, at the   matrix[i][j]=null;